# What is this: Object holding static list of same objects BUT casted to interface?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, collections, interface, static

I encountered the situation mentioned in the topic now more than once and now I want to ask in here for
other opinions, hints, explanations, why someone should/would/ do things like this:

There is an object of class `A`, which implements the interface  `I_1o`

This object has a static member, a collection, typed by interface `I_1`.

The class `A` has an interface-implemented method, which is called `get_instance ( key-params )`.
It looks inside the collection for a specified object fitting the key params and returns the 
relevant object.

Is there a name for this (design pattern, whatever), a reason, a "best practice" explanation, why this seems to be a singleton but on the other hand it is not, just recursive object holding?

If no one understands, what I mean, just let me know, I will try to clarify it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like an `Object Pool` design pattern. Documentation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).

This looks something like this:

```
public class Pool
{
    private static int MAX_ELEMS = 10;

    private static List<Object> instances;

    private static void initialise()
    {
        if(instances == null) {
             instances = new ArrayList<Object>();
             // Initialise all the objects in the list.
        }
    }

    public static Object getInstance(String key)
    {
        for(Object instance : instances) {
             if(instance.equals(key)) { // Just an example
                  return instance;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for this design pattern is to avoid the expensive re-instanciation of objects. If you have a load of, for example, Server connection objects, and you want to limit the amount of connections to the server, then you implement a pattern like this. It will mean that no more than `MAX_ELEMS` objects exist at one time, and it also means that they are not created during use of the program; they are built during some loading period in the program.

Comment: Thx, that helped. Signed as THE ANSWER.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Registry or IdentityMap.

Comment: I dont know, thats why I ask. :-)